# jsmin+ causes high server load in drupal 6

Tags: javascript

I have the JavaScript aggregator module on my site. Whenever I check the jsmin+ checkbox (so it uses jsmin+ instead on jsmin), the server becomes really slow. I have to use jsmin+, instead of jsmin, because jsmin doesn't group JavaScript files correctly, and I get JavaScript errors (Ckeditor and Vertical Tab are breaking).

- Drupal 6.20
- JavaScript aggregator 1.6
- jsmin+ 1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [AdvAgg](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) a try. It works around the limitations of jsmin+

Comment: I'm using drupal 6 and I installed the JSMIN+ in my hosting and don't know how to use in my site, because Pagespeed suggest me to minify the javascript file after enabling AdvAgg. Please help me! my issue is same like this https://drupal.org/node/1842454